# C# Deserialize JSON List of Different Interface Implementations to a list without losing data

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am able to successfully serialize a list containing a mix of Employee and Manager objects to JSON.

However, when I attempt to deserialize the JSON back to a List, I'm losing all of the field data from the subclasses and when I try to cast to either of the subclasses, I get a null value.  How can I deserialize a list of these Users without losing the data in the fields from the Employee and Manager subclasses?

```
[DataContract]
public class User {
  [DataMember]
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Employee : User {
  [DataMember]
  public string JobTitle { get; set; }
}  

[DataContract]
public class Manager : User {
  [DataMember]
  public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT -- HERE IS MY DESERIALIZATION CODE:**

```
// abridged
public void Client() {
  var jsonContent = jsonResponse.Content;
  var entityList = Deserialize<IEnumerable<T>>(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter(), jsonContent);
}

protected T Deserialize<T>(MediaTypeFormatter formatter, string str) where T : class {
    // Write the serialized string to a memory stream.
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
    writer.Write(str);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
    // Deserialize to an object of type T
    return formatter.ReadFromStreamAsync(typeof(T), stream, null, null).Result as T;
}
```

Comment: Just edited the original post. Looks like the JsonMediaTypeFormatter I guess? Can you recommend a better one?

Comment: Edited to add the appropriate DataContract/DataMember attributes as well.  I'm also using those in my actual code.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using `DataContractJsonSerializer` with a set of known types passed as serializer constructor parameter.

I've created a simple test code to demonstrate that:

```
var list = new List<User>() {
    new User { FirstName = "user1", LastName = "user1" },
    new Employee { FirstName = "employee1", LastName = "employee1", JobTitle = "employee1" },
    new Manager() { FirstName = "manager1", LastName = "manager1", Department = "manager1"}
};

var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<User>), new [] { typeof(Employee), typeof(Manager) });

string json;
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, list);
    stream.Position = 0;
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        json = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

List<User> list2;

using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using(var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.Write(json);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        list2 = (List<User>)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this sample! What if I want the entire thing to be dynamic and I don't know what the implementation classes might be?

Comment: Then I don't think it's possible. Serializer would have to search through all available namespaces and look for any class that inherits your `User` class. You can write that part by yourself (using reflection) and pass everything you found into the constructor, but I don't think it's gonna be really efficient code.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. I'm trying to think of this from an API client's perspective.  I'm returning a list of these different implementations of the same interface in the same list.  Is that a bad practice? Do people typically have different resource URL's for different implementation types?

Comment: With this approach, it seems like the downside of this is that the type field gets serialized into the JSON with the rest of the data.  I'm not sure I want to expose that information to the API Client...